# PostgreSQL with DBeaver, password?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am a student. I've created a Rails/React project using PostgreSQL. I downloaded DBeaver so that I can view my database but cannot get DBeaver to connect, and have spent a couple of hours trying to solve this.

I attempt to set up DBeaver for PostgreSQL, click "New Connection," leave all defaults set and click "Finish" when I'm met with the following error:

```
The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

I am pretty certain that I never entered a password for this database. I saw it suggested that the default password is "postgres" but I tried that with no success. In terminal when I run "psql --list" I can see my DB's name and I can see that I am the owner.

I am running a Debian distro, if that makes any difference. I installed DBrowser through Synaptic. I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Right mouse on the connection in the *Database Navigator* - **Edit Connection** and give in the password in the *Connection settings* window?

Comment: There is never any connection to start with, and I have never set a password. There is no password set in the "Connection Settings" window. I am trying to do an initial setup, it isn't as though I've previously had a connection which I now cannot access.

Comment: Your database might be configured to demand passwords for TCP connections, but not for local socket connections.  What is in your pg_hba.conf?

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to solve it by resetting my psql password (even though I had never set one).